# Weird RNG behavior in C++11 when defined and called in different places

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I'm trying to write a multi-file program including the following code related to random number generation:

**in help.h file:**

```
extern random_device rand_dev;
extern ranlux48 rand_eng;
extern uniform_real_distribution<> zero2one_dist;
```

**in help.cpp file:**

```
#include "help.h"
random_device rand_dev;
ranlux48 rand_eng{ rand_dev() };
uniform_real_distribution<> zero2one_dist(0, 1);
```

**in main.cpp file**

```
#include "help.h"
//identical as help.cpp, just for illustration of the problem
random_device rand_dev1;
ranlux48 rand_eng1{ rand_dev1() };
uniform_real_distribution<> zero2one_dist1(0, 1);
//random number generation
float rnd1 = zero2one_dist1(rand_eng1);
float rnd2 = zero2one_dist(rand_eng);
//main function
int main()
{
    //another random number generation.
    float rnd3 = zero2one_dist(rand_eng);
    //output
    cout << rnd1 << endl << rnd2 << endl << rnd3 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The desired result is outputting three random number between 0 and 1, however, `rnd1` and `rnd3` generates proper result but `rnd2` keeps 0?!

I'm totally confused here, what's the difference between definitions in external file **help.h** and in **main.cpp** and what's the difference between a call inside and outside main()?

In my real work, I would need to write the code in the form of `rnd2`, but now it won't work and I don't know why.

Can anyone illustrate the difference between `rnd1`, `rnd2` and `rnd3` and get `rnd2` to work? Thanks!

Comment: There is no guarantee for the initialization order across translation units. `rnd2` may be initialized before or after `zero2one_dist`. Use form `rnd3` if you really want an external distribution object, or a helper function.

Comment: @spectras I wrote a help function in **help.cpp** file: `float rand_zero2one() { return zero2one_dist(rand_eng); }` however, calling this function like `rnd2=rand_zero2one()` won't work either...

Comment: @Wjx same problem, since `rnd2` is a static in one translation unit it might get initialized before help.cpp has even executed its constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee for the initialization order across translation units. `rnd2` may be initialized before or after `zero2one_dist`. Use form `rnd3` if you really want an external distribution object, or a helper function, for instance:

```
float rand_zero2one()
{
   static random_device rand_dev;
   static ranlux48 rand_eng{ rand_dev() };
   static uniform_real_distribution<> zero2one_dist(0, 1);
   return zero2one_dist(rand_eng);
}
```

This guarantees the static variables are initialized before the function is first called. Put it in your `help` file and make that available instead of the extern variables.

Or even better, if your intent is to make it a singleton, do so. Put those into a [singleton class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern) and then use `MySingletonGenerator::instance().nextValue()`.

Comment: Thanks~ but here's a small additional question: I would like to be able to call a same `rand_dev` and `rand_eng` in multiple functions, is that possible?

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I've read something about singleton, it proved quite useful!(I'm a beginner in C++ as you can see......) Thanks for your help a lot! ~

Comment: @Wjx yes, your second comment actually answers your first comment: by making your generator a singleton class you can use it from multiple places. You're then free to put whatever methods you need in it.

Comment: @Wjx don't fall in love with singletons, there are lots of arguments against them.